# How to format decimal number precision

Tags: java

How to format the decimal number precision like given below:

`double d = 1/3` returns `0.3333333333333333` and mathematically **3** is repeated **infinitely**.

`d = ((double)3)/ (double)41;` returns `0.07317073170731707` and here **07317** is repeated.

Now, the ask to format the output like below

`0.3333333333333333` should be formatted to `0.(3)` as 3 is repeated.

Similarly `0.07317073170731707` should be formatted to `0.(07317)` as **07317** repeated

I had looked into `DecimalFormat` class but I am able to format only number of precisions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.'('##')'");

        double d = ((double)1)/ (double)3;
        System.out.println("formatted "+formatter.format(d));
        System.out.println(d);


        d = ((double)1)/ (double)2;
        System.out.println("formatted "+formatter.format(d));
        System.out.println(d);


        d = ((double)3)/ (double)41;
        System.out.println("formatted "+formatter.format(d));
        System.out.println(d);

    }
```

Output:

```
formatted 0.33()
0.3333333333333333
formatted 0.5()
0.5
formatted 0.07()
0.07317073170731707
```

Is there any built-in class in *Java* available to achieve the same?

Comment: *Is there any built-in class in Java available to achieve the same?* No.

Comment: How to frame the logic.. the challenge is identifying the repeating number.

Comment: It's very difficult to know whether it's actually repeating, given the limited precision of type `double`. How do you know that 0.33333333333333333 is not actually the non-repeating number 0.33333333333333333333333333903458934785389?

Comment: I think it is not difficult to find out the repeating part, if it is not to long, while computing the number. When the result is there as a double you can't identify repeating numbers any more.

Comment: A *double* doesn't repeat indefinitely. They store up to a number of fractional digits and stop there. If you take a double value and try to find a repeating pattern, you won't find any because it always eventually stops. If you want to find actual repeating fractional digits, you must work with the integers, and compute their division yourself.

Comment: @kumesana Could you add an answer or point me to any documents if any. At the moment I am not able absorb it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes. That's agreed. what would I use instead of double?

Comment: I don't know of a document. I could attempt a more lengthy explanation if I wasn't currently supposed to do the work I'm paid for.

Comment: @kumesana okay - No worries. Do it on your free time. At least I should not do `double d = 1/3` but I should come up with logic for the division. I shall update post if I have some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if you only have a String representation, to begin with, there is no way to tell if there is actually some repeating part to it or if the precision simply is not high enough.

However, from your sample, it seems that you actually want to find the repeating part of fractions where you know both the numerator and denominator as an exact integer. That is not too hard of a problem; for example, you can look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/decimal-expansion-of-a-rational-number

=== Update ===

I was working on a class representing a rational number with numerator and denominator as BigIntegers (and assumed to be reduced as far as possible). There I implemented a method to produce a representation as decimal String and came up with the following:

```
public String toDecimalString() {

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    var remainders = new HashMap<BigInteger, Integer>();

    if(!isNonNegative()) result.append("-");
    var divAndRem = numerator.abs().divideAndRemainder(denominator);
    result.append(divAndRem[0].toString());

    if(isWholeNumber()) return result.toString();

    result.append(".");

    int currentPosition = result.length();
    remainders.put(divAndRem[1], currentPosition);

    while(!divAndRem[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        divAndRem = divAndRem[1].multiply(BigInteger.TEN).divideAndRemainder(denominator);
        result.append(divAndRem[0].toString());
        if(remainders.containsKey(divAndRem[1])) {
            int periodStart = remainders.get(divAndRem[1]);
            return result.substring(0, periodStart)+"["+result.substring(periodStart)+"]";
        }
        remainders.put(divAndRem[1], ++currentPosition);
    }

    return result.toString();

}
```

Comment: They can be `long` too.

Comment: Sure, even `BigInteger` and such. I just meant integers as in numbers without fractional part.

Comment: In case you still need it: I added a sample solution I was working on recently.

Comment: I was able to follow the link you have already provided, but thanks. But I was just wondering that we can just use `double` and convert the precision of result after devision to string and find the position of (`indexOf`) of first character. Let's say `10/3` lead to 3.33333.. so the indexOf `3` here is `1`  and take substring between 0 and 1

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna Care to elaborate or give an example where it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not know of such a class, maybe mathematicians know. The problem is that one a part of the infinite representations are turned to finite ones, and calculating with repeated groups must be done symbolically, not with some immediate binary numbers. *(A nice student project maybe.)*

`double` is flawed. One could make one's own class based on `BigDecimal` that can identify repeating decimals, and store such "infinite" numbers. Many infinite numbers like **π** still will be unusable.

Or you can create a rational number class with (numerator, denominator).

And for some rare cases you can avoid repeating decimals by switching the number base,
as Integer/Long can work with diferent bases and one can build upon that:

0.1 base 3 = 0.33333... base 10

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method that takes into account simple repetitions, like the one below.

```
public static double reformatNumber(double number) {
  String s = String.valueOf(number);

  String[] split = s.split("\\.");

  String result = split[1].substring(0,8); // Length to consider
  String actualDigit = "";
  String lastDigit = "";
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= result.length(); i++) {
    actualDigit = result.substring(i-1,i);
    if (actualDigit.equals(lastDigit)) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    lastDigit = actualDigit;
    if (counter == 3) { // Number of repetitions in a row required
      result = result.substring(0,i-1);
    }
  }
  s = split[0]+"."+result;

  return Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

If you want consider repetitions of two or more simply modify the last method to save two digits at once, like this.

```
public static double reformatNumber(double number) {
  String s = String.valueOf(number);

  String[] split = s.split("\\.");

  String result = split[1].substring(0,8);
  String actualDigit = "";
  String lastDigit = "";
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= result.length(); i++) {
    actualDigit = result.substring(i-1,i);
    if (actualDigit.equals(lastDigit)) {
      counter++;
    } else if (i%4 == 0 && (actualDigit+lastDigit).equals(result.substring(i-4,i-2))) { 
      // Every four cycles checks if the last digit and the current one 
      // are equals to the last two digits before the last digit
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    lastDigit = actualDigit;
    if (counter == 3) {
      result = result.substring(0,i-1);
      break;
    }
  }
  s = split[0]+"."+result;

  return Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but the expectation was the solution should work for all possible cases.